# How to compile a MXML file to AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml

I want to compile one class from MXML to as3 as a learning experience.  What is the best way to do this?

The class had dependencies on other classes in my project but I don't think that should matter if I am just compiling it to as3 right?

What is the easiest way to do this?  Currently I have Flash Builder 4 (in Eclipse) but I would be happy just to use a command line compiler if that exists.

*I was sure that this question must have been asked before but I could not find it.  If it has already been asked please close this and point me towards the older question/*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `keep-generated-actionscript` command line option [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html).

You can use it both in command line and [from Flash Builder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67670-7ffe.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a95).

Comment: It is located in your Flex SDK. More info is [over there](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f14.html).